# Avoid duplicate reference / import of external javascript library in Typescript when using AMD modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, amd

Lets say I am using `--module AMD` to get AMD module support with Typescript and use `requirejs`. Now, using the `jquery.ts.d` from [DefinetelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) I came up with the following minimal example:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
import $ = require("jquery");

export class Greeter
{
    sayHello() {
       $('#mydiv').text('hello world');
    }
}
```

One can clearly see that I have to reference `jQuery`two times: One time via the `///<reference ... />` statement and one time via the `import jquery = require("jquery")` statement.

Now, if I omit the `///<reference ... />` part, the typescript compiler `tsc` will complain about the unknown `$`variable. On the other hand, if I leave out the `import` statement, compilation will work but at runtime `jQuery`will not be included (as it is not in the list of required components in the compiled sourcecode).

So the only way I see is to always include both statements, which feels wrong to me as I am repeating myself. I this the "expected way"(TM) or am I just missing something here?

Comment: Can you conditionally import jquery?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend adding a `vendor.d.ts` file that consolidates all your external definitions like :

```
/// <reference path="./jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./other/other.d.ts" />
```

And then you only reference `vendor.d.ts` :

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/vendor.d.ts" />
import $ = require("jquery");
```

BTW, if you are using tsd https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd it creates a `tsd.d.ts` file for you that plays the role of `vendor.d.ts`

Comment: Didn't know about `tsd.d.ts`, best answer so far! However I still have the trouble of remembering to perform an `import $ = require('jquery');` (and similiar for knockout, underscore, ...) in every .ts file I used - if I forget it, compilation succeeds but there might be runtime errors

Comment: Btw. I found out how to make sure not to forget the `import` statement: I now only use external modules, and either I export a single class per file (=external module) using the `export = <ClassName>` syntax ([see here](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript)) or when exporting multiple classes from a file (=external module) by aliasing them via `import MyClass = modulename.MyClass`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file called `jquery.d.ts` in the same path, and that file is written with a top-level export (instead of a `declare module "jquery" {`), then you don't need the reference tag.

You could also pass all of your .d.ts files as explicit arguments to `tsc`

Otherwise, there's no way for the compiler to know where to find type information about the jQuery module.

Comment: Well the .d.ts come via DefinetelyTyped and are not in the same path as jquery.

Comment: Well I'd rather get rid of the import statement. Missing the reference statement at compile time will result in an error, missing the import statement will only produce an error at runtime, which is more error-prone IMHO